# Get Facebook wall post (stream) photo URL using FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the URL for the original image when a user posts in my wall. So for I'm doing this to retrieve the wall posts:

```
SELECT attachment, actor_id, type, place, message, description FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```

In attachment is where the photo info lays, however, I tried uploading different photos of different sizes and the parameters aren't always the same.

```
"attachment": {
        "media": [
          {
            "href": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=&set=a.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
            "alt": "novo post de imagem", 
            "type": "photo", 
            "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1461152_604407632928327_57092530_s.jpg", 
            "photo": {
              "aid": "************_1715", 
              "pid": "************_1073741835", 
              "fbid": 604407632928327, 
              "owner": ************, 
              "index": 1, 
              "width": 1024, 
              "height": 768, 
              "images": [
                {
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1461152_604407632928327_57092530_s.jpg", 
                  "width": 130, 
                  "height": 97
                }, 
                {
                  "src": "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/s720x720/1461152_604407632928327_57092530_n.jpg", 
                  "width": 720, 
                  "height": 540
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ], 
        "name": "", 
        "caption": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "properties": [
        ], 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
        "fb_object_type": "photo", 
        "fb_object_id": "************_1073741835"
      }, 
      "actor_id": ************, 
      "type": 247, 
      "place": null, 
      "message": "novo post de imagem", 
      "description": null
    }
```

Since I can't always get the original photo URL with this data, I was thinking of getting the photo from the `photo` or `photo_src` tables, however, every code I have in this JSON does not work to retrieve any image, and the `aid` and `pid` have to be passed as strings because of the underscore.

My question is: what code in here can I use to get the photo from another table (possibly `photo` or `photo_src`) and what is the correct query to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. I was missing the `user_photos` permission in my access token. My code is fine and the ID I should use to query the photo is the `pid`.

However I think some kind of error would be nice, given that a null result lead me to believe my query was wrong, not that I had a missing permission.

So the query should be something like this:

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid = "************_1073741835"
```